# How does Big O notation work?

Tags: python, function, time-complexity, big-o

Ok so I'm fairly new to coding and I am to approximate a WCET T(a, b) and complexity of a function. Example function:

```
def testFunction(self):
    x = 0
    for r in range(a):
        for c in range(b):
            if testFunction2(r, c):
                x = x + 1
return x
```

I understand that the complexity of this function is quadratic O(N^2) but I'm not sure on approximating the WCET?

Also isn't there only two assignments in that function, being:

```
x = 0
```

and

```
x = x + 1
```

?
If so, how do I express the assignments with T(a, b)?

Maths has never been my strong point but I want to learn how to do this. None of the materials I've read explains it in a way I understand.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def testFunction(self):
    x = 0                               # 1
    for r in range(a):                  # a
        for c in range(b):              # b
            if testFunction2(r, c):     # a*b
                x = x + 1               # depends testFunction2
    return x                            # 1
```

WCET for this function a*b where a=n b=n then you can say O(n^2) 
if always testFunction2 returns True then `x = x +1` will execute a*b times but it wont effect the sum of execution time.
Finally you sum all this exection time:

```
(1 + a + b + a*b + a*b + 1)
2 + a + b + 2*a*b
```

for example, while n = 1000 and a=b=n

```
2 + 1000 + 1000 + 2*1000*1000
2002 + 2000000
```

so when you evalute this result you will see 2002 is nothing while you have 2000000.

Comment: Ok I can make sense of that and it is helpful. So would you be right in saying: 'the worst case execution time is: T(a, b) = 2 + a + b + 2ab'. Would that answer what the execution time is?

Comment: That's brilliant. Thanks for your help. Also with Big O notation, would the run-time complexity for this function be O(N^2) because it has one for loop nested inside another?

Comment: yes if you assume your a and b equals to n `if a,b = n then O(n^2)`

Comment: Ah so otherwise it would be O(ab^2)?

Comment: no actually it will be just a*b it comes from math for example lets say a=2 and b=2 so a*b = 2*2 but we can write 2*2 as 2^2 its equals. `a=n, b=n => a*b = n*n = n^2`

Comment: Ok well as there is no 'n' in that function at all, would the answer to 'what is the run-time complexity' be 'the run-time complexity of testFunction is O(ab)'? Would that be the correct answer or am I not understanding something?

Comment: O(ab) is the correct. just when we talk about computer science, runtime complexity use O(n^2). The most important part is while a,b=n where n is a big integer

Comment: Sorry, like I said in my post, maths isn't my strong point so takes me a bit longer to understand. So when you see places showing a complexity as 'O(n^2)', 'O(n)', 'O(log n)'. Is the 'n' just used for example purposes? So the 'n' is actually replaced by whatever is in the function you're measuring the complexity of? I hope I'm not annoying you with the questions.

Comment: Also, if I was basing it on assignment statements rather than operations, wouldn't '(1 + a + b + a×b + a×b + 1)' then be (1 + a×b) because `x = 0` executes once and then `x = x + 1` executes a×b times?

Comment: yes thats right, but your `if` condition must be always True in that case.

Comment: Indeed yes, as it is for the worst case. I really appreciate your help. I understand how it works now so can apply it to my studies. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

For a Worst Case Execution Time, you can simply assume there is an input specifically crafted to make your program slow. In this case that would be testfunction2 always returns true.

Within the body of the loop, the assignment `x = x + 1` happens `a * b` times in the worst case.

Instead of describing this as O(N^2), I would describe it as O(ab), and then note for a ~= b ~= N that is O(N^2)

Comment: I am understanding all but the last line you put. Isn't Big O complexity for this shown as O(N^2)? Also how is the WCET approximated with T(a, b) expressing the number of assignments? I do understand how the assignment in the for loop happens 'a*b' times though. Thank you

Comment: well it can't be O( any function of N ) because there is *no mention of N* in the program.